# Error comverting date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, format, runtime-error, simpledateformat

I want to convert a date in format dd MMM yyyy (23 May 2015) to yyyy-MM-dd.

The code I'm using:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM dd", Locale.ITALY);
try {
    Date varDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ITALY);
    date = simpleDateFormat.format(varDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The variable date before conversion: 23 May 2015
After conversion: 2015-05-23

Unfortunately I'm getting an error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23 May 2015" (at offset 3)
```

Comment: a string containing the current date in the format dd MMM yyyy

Comment: @qwertz I think he meant "what is the actual value contained in the variable date you are passing to this method". Is it "23 May 2015"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find that in Italian, May is "Maggio".

Note that it says "offset 3" in the exception, which is the fourth character (we are counting from zero). That is the month string.

Also, you have "dd" as the year format instead of "yyyy".

Comment: Oh that totally makes sense now. Thank you :) Can accept answer in 2 minutes

Comment: No problem. Now I know what "DiMaggio" means.

Answer (score 2):

At first there's a typo in original format. It should be  "dd MMM yyyy". And secondly the locale is set to Italy and it means input  month should be in Italian, not in English. Or you should change locale parameter.